# How would I, or how much would it cost, to remove this stone pond?

Tags: removal, stone

New homeowner here.  This is in my backyard.  It is overgrown and non-functional in any way.  I'm honestly not 100% sure what it was, but I assume it was a pond.

The back of the pond is joined with mortar or cement or something.  I was wondering how someone would remove it.  Would a sledgehammer break through it, or would a jackhammer be required?

There are stones all around the area from it.  I've just been throwing them in the pond for the time being, so that the mess is confined to one place.  An image of it is below (sorry for not mowing before taking the photo, lol).

[image: Stone Pond]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly break it up with a sledge . But then you still have a pile of rock. Maybe you would like a rock garden . Personally I like ponds ( have 3 ).

Answer (score 2):

This is called a grotto, it's essentially a shrine to the Virgin Mary.  Since it is not a structure designed to support anything more than the rocks and contain the water, the concrete is most likely just an inche or two thick and easily busted up with a sledge hammer.

The statue has value to a Catholic, you might want to put an add in Craig's List and offer the rocks and statue free to anyone for busting it up and hauling it away.

Comment: There's a catholic church across the street.  I'm not religous, but I figured I donate it to them.  This statue in particular isn't worth much (~$150 - $200 max), and is in pretty bad shape (needs to be power washed and repainted, and the detail is wearing).